# not all code paths return a value in the error handling part of the code

Tags: c#, exception, return-value

I have a method created to connect to the API and get the data and return it. If there is issue connecting, I want to throw a customized error message instead of the generic one I have in my code. How do I tweak else part of my code so I can use customized error message. ( popup or inline message etc.). 
Here is my code:

```
    //Method to connect to the SHDAPI ....
        public async static Task<string> SHDAPI(string url, string requestData, string errorMessage)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            //Converting to HTTP content since postasync below needs it...
            HttpContent myHttpContent = new StringContent(requestData);

            //Creating the ContentType header.....
            myHttpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            //Sending the POST request to create a thread post ....
            HttpResponseMessage APIRequest = await client.PostAsync(url, myHttpContent);

            if (APIRequest.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // Read the HTTP response content....
                HttpContent responseContent = APIRequest.Content;

                // Read the response content as string.....
                return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            if (APIRequest.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                // Read the HTTP response content....
                HttpContent responseContent = APIRequest.Content;
                // Read the response content as string.....

                return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }


            else
            {

                throw new Exception("Error connecting to " + url + " ! Status: " + APIRequest.StatusCode);

                //Pop up the server or network issue message...
                //Instantiate the controls class for using the progress bar and other controls in this function...
                myControls mycontrols = new myControls();

                //Instantiate the frames class for using in this function since this.Frame.Navigate can't be used...
                Frame myframe = new Frame();

                mycontrols.popupMessages(errorMessage, "Network or Server error!");

//              mycontrols.popupMessages("There was an issue getting your messages from the Message Center, please try again later", "Network or Server error!");

                //Navigate back to the main page....
                myframe.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            }
        }
```

The issue is in the else part of the code, if I remove the throw new exception line, then my function is expecting a return value from this part of my path too. How can I use the customized error messaging and still get rid of the error message of all paths returning a value?

Comment: return null; but I think that you should review your code as the else should throw.

Comment: yes, returning null is what I was looking for. Thank You Pedro. The kid ...

Answer (score 1):

Just throw the exception as the very last statement in the else part of the function. As soon as you throw an exception whatever comes next is not executed.
Which is why you don't need to return anything. Exceptions are also a way of returning, but then with an error.

Comment: the question is if he removes the throw.

Comment: No it is not. He want the customized errors to come out and that is done by moving the exception lower. Removing the throw is just an attempt at obtaining the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use try-catch-finally:

```
     try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            //Converting to HTTP content since postasync below needs it...
            HttpContent myHttpContent = new StringContent(requestData);

            //Creating the ContentType header.....
            myHttpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            //Sending the POST request to create a thread post ....
            HttpResponseMessage APIRequest = await client.PostAsync(url, myHttpContent);

            if (APIRequest.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // Read the HTTP response content....
                HttpContent responseContent = APIRequest.Content;

                // Read the response content as string.....
                return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            if (APIRequest.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                // Read the HTTP response content....
                HttpContent responseContent = APIRequest.Content;
                // Read the response content as string.....

                return await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Error connecting to " + url + " ! Status: " + APIRequest.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display your custom error message
        }
        finally
        {
            //Instantiate the controls class for using the progress bar and other controls in this function...
            myControls mycontrols = new myControls();

            //Instantiate the frames class for using in this function since this.Frame.Navigate can't be used...
            Frame myframe = new Frame();

            mycontrols.popupMessages(errorMessage, "Network or Server error!");
            //mycontrols.popupMessages("There was an issue getting your messages from the Message Center, please try again later", "Network or Server error!");

            //Navigate back to the main page....
            myframe.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

    }
```